# ValueError: Input 0 of layer "model" is incompatible with the layer: expected shape=(None, 1536, 2048, 3), found shape=(None, 106)

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, google-colaboratory

When I Creating a Unet model architecture with loss function pixel cross entropy I got an Value Error
I am sharing my code here https://codeshare.io/oQEOpp

My error is
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
 in <cell line: 63>()
61
62 # Define loss function and optimizer
---> 63 model = unet((1224, 106, 3)) # Assuming RGB images
64 model.compile(optimizer=Adam(), loss=SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(), metrics=['accuracy'])
65

3 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras/src/layers/merging/concatenate.py in build(self, input_shape)
129                 )
130                 if len(unique_dims) > 1:

--> 131                     raise ValueError(err_msg)
132
133     def _merge_function(self, inputs):

ValueError: A `Concatenate` layer requires inputs with matching shapes except for the concatenation axis. Received: input_shape=[(None, 153, 13, 512), (None, 152, 12, 512)]

Can you please resolve my issue ? Thankyou in advance